# R: multicollinearity issues using glib(), Bayesian Model Averaging (BMA-package)

Tags: r, bayesian

I am experiencing difficulties estimating a BMA-model via glib(), due to multicollinearity issues, even though I have clearly specified which columns to use. Please find the details below.

The data I'll be using for the estimation via Bayesian Model Averaging:

```
Cij <- c(357848,766940,610542,482940,527326,574398,146342,139950,227229,67948,
 352118,884021,933894,1183289,445745,320996,527804,266172,425046,
 290507,1001799,926219,1016654,750816,146923,495992,280405,
 310608,1108250,776189,1562400,272482,352053,206286,
 443160,693190,991983,769488,504851,470639,
 396132,937085,847498,805037,705960,
 440832,847631,1131398,1063269,
 359480,1061648,1443370,
 376686,986608,
 344014)
n <- length(Cij);
TT <- trunc(sqrt(2*n))
i <- rep(1:TT,TT:1); #row numbers: year of origin
j <- sequence(TT:1) #col numbers: year of development
k <- i+j-1 #diagonal numbers: year of payment
#Since k=i+j-1, we have to  leave out another dummy in order to avoid  multicollinearity
k <- ifelse(k == 2, 1, k)
```

I want to evaluate the effect of *i* and *j* both via levels and factors, but of course not in the same model. Since I can decide to include *i* and *j* as factors, levels, or not include them at all and for *k* either to include as level, or exclude, there are a total of 18 (3x3x2) models. This brings us to the following data frame:

```
X <- data.frame(Cij,i.factor=as.factor(i),j.factor=as.factor(j),k,i,j)
X <- model.matrix(Cij ~ -1 + i.factor + j.factor + k + i + j,X) 
X <- as.data.frame(X[,-1])
```

Next, via the following declaration I specify which variables to consider in each of the 18 models. According to me, no linear dependence exists in these specifications.

```
model.set <- rbind(
  c(rep(0,9),rep(0,9),0,0,0),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(0,9),0,1,0),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(0,9),0,0,1),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(0,9),1,0,0),
  c(rep(1,9),rep(0,9),0,0,0),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(1,9),0,0,0),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(0,9),0,1,1),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(0,9),1,1,0),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(1,9),0,1,0),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(0,9),1,0,1),
  c(rep(1,9),rep(0,9),0,0,1),
  c(rep(1,9),rep(0,9),1,0,0),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(1,9),1,0,0),
  c(rep(1,9),rep(1,9),0,0,0),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(0,9),1,1,1),
  c(rep(0,9),rep(1,9),1,1,0),
  c(rep(1,9),rep(0,9),1,0,1),
  c(rep(1,9),rep(1,9),1,0,0))
```

Then I call the glib() function, telling it to select the specified columns from X according to model.set.

```
library(BMA)
model.glib <- glib(X,Cij,error="poisson", link="log",models=model.set)
```

which results in the error

```
Error in glim(x, y, n, error = error, link = link, scale = scale) : X matrix is not full rank
```

The function first checks whether the matrix is f.c.r, before it evaluates which columns to select from *X* via model.set. How do I circumvent this, or is there any other way to include all 18 models in the glib() function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A casual perusal of the `glib.data.frame()` function, and the subsequent `glim()` function that's throwing your error shows that the fully specified model is estimated before you ever get to the sub-model calculations.  I believe this is necessary to establish the baseline deviance calculations for estimating your overall averaged model uncertainty?  In your case there might not be a workaround?